# What is the difference between a Facebook Page "Like" and an external URL "Like"? And will the "user_likes" permission scope give access to both?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-fql

I'd like to pull a list of all Facebook "Likes" for a user, whether they are Facebook pages or external URLs.

Example:

If you "Like" the [Facebook Platform](http://www.facebook.com/platform), I know I can see it via the `/me/likes` API call.

However, if you like an [external URL](http://techcrunch.com/2011/09/14/facebook-launches-twitter-like-subscriptions-lets-you-share-with-unlimited-users/), I'm not sure how to pull that. Are both supposed to be pulled via the `/me/likes` call? Or is there another call to handle external *likes*?

Further, what about newsfeed / stream likes?  For example, if I "Like" a photo, video, status or link that I see in my stream, is that accessible via the API? If so, how is this accessed?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, user_likes will give you access to both.

You can access external *likes* as you wish through the [Graph API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform#Graph_API) endpoint `/me/likes`, as long as they're not articles. Objects with type "article" do not represent real-world objects and as such, we don't provide on a person's profile. We mention this (albeit obscurely) on the [Open Graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform#Open_Graph_protocol) documentation page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/#types

So if you go to my fake movie object page at

http://fbsb.hoodlu.ms/so_7436857/video2.html

and click like, that will show up when you access your *likes* on https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes.

Try it using the Graph API explorer:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Flikes

If you want the URLs that someone has liked, use this [FQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Query_Language) query:

```sql
SELECT url FROM url_like WHERE user_id = me()
```

More information is available at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/url_like/.

If you want to access the *likes* from a post, photo, video, etc. you'll need to use the `like` and `stream` FQL tables. To just pull out the likes (of posts/photos/videos) for the current user:

```sql
SELECT user_id, object_id, post_id FROM like WHERE user_id=me()
```

From there, you would query the `stream` table for the post to get more information.

`like` table documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/.

`stream` table documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/

Answer (score 2):

Facebook now has two ways to read likes. If you would like to get the likes of an external URL you try this:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/me/og.likes/[ID_FACEBOOKOBJECT]
```

And if you wish get the likes from an internal Facebook page (fan page,profile,photo like) try this:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/me/likes/[ID_FACEBOOKOBJECT]
```

Checkout: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer